# Python: Is there an easy way for "approximate lookup" in dataframes available?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

**What I try to do:**

I have two data frames, each contains 1 Mio+ rows.

*df_input1* contains an EventID and the exact time stamp when the related event occured.

*df_input2* contains a list of so called PO numbers and the time stamp from when this PO number is valid.

The goal is to map the valid PO number to the corresponding event **based on the time stamps.**
That means if an event occurs at 3:30:00 then the PO number (valid from 3:00:00) should be mapped to this event in an addtional column and so on (see example *df_result*)

```
df_input1

            EventStart  EventID
0  01.02.2019  4:00:00       10
1  01.02.2019  5:42:43       25
2  01.02.2019  6:14:07       24
3  01.02.2019  7:54:50       25
4  01.02.2019  8:51:56       24
5  01.02.2019  9:19:20       24
6  01.02.2019 10:07:41       23
7  01.02.2019 11:18:48       17


df_input2

              PO_Start  PO_ID
0  01.02.2019  3:00:00      1
1  01.02.2019  5:00:00      2
2  01.02.2019  7:00:00      3
3  01.02.2019  9:00:00      4

df_result

            EventStart  EventID  PO_ID
0  01.02.2019  4:00:00       10      1
1  01.02.2019  5:42:43       25      2
2  01.02.2019  6:14:07       24      2
3  01.02.2019  7:54:50       25      3
4  01.02.2019  8:51:56       24      3
5  01.02.2019  9:19:20       24      4
6  01.02.2019 10:07:41       23      4
7  01.02.2019 11:18:48       17      4
```

**Specific question:**
Is there already a defined mapping function available in order to do this? Maybe as numpy function?
I tried already to do this with two related **FOR loops** which are checking row by row. This actually works quite well but applying this approach to dataframes with 1 Mio+ events, this takes an huge amount of processing time and is not really efficient.

Comment: may be you can take a look at `pd.merge_asof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anky_91 provided the right hint to solve the problem.

Using `pd.merge_asof` is a fast way to map data of two tables as required in the above use case/problem description.

Thanks a lot.